# Pygame window instantly closing?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

When I try to run this pygame code it instantly closes??

The window doesn't close instantly when I stop drawing text, so I know I must've done something wrong.

```
import pygame
background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
(width, height) = (1920, 1080)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('fat')
screen.fill(background_colour)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
color = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
pygame.display.flip()
running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False




text = ""

while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        vanishingtext += event.unicode
        text += event.unicode
      elif event.type == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
         text = text[:-1]        
      elif event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:
        interpret(text)
        text = ""
      else:
        pass

        txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
        screen.blit(txt_surface, (50, 100))
```

i expect for a screen to appear that allows me to type and backspace, if i press enter the text should completely disappear and a function should run that will interpret the string.  i haven't defined interpet as a function yet, but i'm doing it after i've figured out if i can even make it work on a screen.

Comment: Where are you getting the function `interpret()` from? `vanishingtext` is never initialized. Your last two statements seem to be on the wrong level of  indentation.

Comment: I fixed those now, I erased ```interpret()``` and ```vanishingtext``` and fixed the indenting.  it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is not calling `pygame.init()`.  Also there's two event loops, the second of which will just drop straight-through once the `running` becomes `False`.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

(width, height) = ( 400, 200)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('fat')

background_colour = pygame.Color('white')
color   = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
font    = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
clock   = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
text    = ''

while running:

    # handle events and user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if ( event.key >= pygame.K_SPACE and event.key <= pygame.K_z ):
                # Append key-stroke's character
                text += event.unicode
            elif ( event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE ):
                text = text[:-1]
            elif ( event.key == pygame.K_RETURN ):
                print("interpret(text) - NOT IMPLEMENTED")
                text = ""

    # repaint the screen
    screen.fill(background_colour)
    txt_surface = font.render(text, True, color)
    screen.blit(txt_surface, (50, 100))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60) # limit FPS
```

This code gives me  a window titled "fat" with a white background. Typing on an english keyboard gives me blue letters, which can be backspaced.  Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> is somewhat handled.

Comment: I tried merging the while loops.


`while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        text += event.unicode
    elif event.type == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
         text = text[:-1]        
    elif event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:
        text = ""
    else:
        pass`
The window still works but if you know what's wrong could you help?  I'm trying to make whatever I type, appear on my screen.  It's not working, any ideas why not?
The indentation doesn't work in my comment sorry!

Comment: Ik it explicitly says not to say thanks, but I'm going to just say thanks so much.  I've just began on python and I'm extremely grateful for the help.  Have an incredible day.